# Error in numba @njit when indexing numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, compiler-errors, numba

I'm trying to build up with numba a function which returns a numpy array evaluated over another array
I'll post a simple code without njit:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def prueba(arr, eva):
    mask = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        mask.append(arr[i])
    return eva[mask]
```

It works correctly, as expected:

```
>>> prueba(np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([5,6,7,8,9,10]))
array([6, 7, 8])
```

Nevertheless, when I try to compile it with numba in nopython mode (@njit) it throws an error

```
@nb.njit
def prueba(arr, eva):
    mask = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        mask.append(arr[i])
    return eva[mask]

>>> prueba(np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([5,6,7,8,9,10]))
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-111474f08921> in <module>
----> 1 prueba(np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([5,6,7,8,9,10]))

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    399                 e.patch_message(msg)
    400 
--> 401             error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    402         except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    403             # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/dispatcher.py in error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    342                 raise e
    343             else:
--> 344                 reraise(type(e), e, None)
    345 
    346         argtypes = []

~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    666             value = tp()
    667         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 668             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    669         raise value
    670 

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function getitem>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(int64, 1d, C), list(int64))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 1:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 2:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 3:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 4:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 5:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 6:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 7:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 8:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 9:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 10:
    All templates rejected with literals.
In definition 11:
    All templates rejected without literals.
In definition 12:
    TypeError: unsupported array index type list(int64) in [list(int64)]
    raised from /home/donielix/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/typing/arraydecl.py:71
In definition 13:
    TypeError: unsupported array index type list(int64) in [list(int64)]
    raised from /home/donielix/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/typing/arraydecl.py:71
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
[1] During: typing of intrinsic-call at <ipython-input-8-1b5c9f1a65d5> (6)
[2] During: typing of static-get-item at <ipython-input-8-1b5c9f1a65d5> (6)

File "<ipython-input-8-1b5c9f1a65d5>", line 6:
def prueba(arr, eva):
    <source elided>
        mask.append(arr[i])
    return eva[mask]
    ^
```

So my question is, why this simple code gives an unexpected error? And how should I workaround this issue?

Comment: So you only need to index `b`? `b[a]`?

Comment: `mask` is a list.  In `numpy` `eva[mask]` converts to `eva[np.array(mask)]`.  It looks like `numba` doesn't do that, and instead rejects array indexing with the list.  This may be test code, but why are you building a list from an array, and then using that list as index?  That's poorly written for both `numpy` and `numba`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from the documentation:

> A subset of advanced indexing is also supported: only one advanced
>   index is allowed, and it has to be a one-dimensional array (it can be
>   combined with an arbitrary number of basic indices as well).
>   https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html#array-access

Therefore to make your code work you have to convert `mask` to a `numpy array`:

```
@nb.njit
def prueba(arr, eva):
    mask = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        mask.append(arr[i])
    mask_as_array = np.array(mask)
    return eva[mask_as_array]

prueba(np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([5,6,7,8,9,10]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your indexing using `numpy`:

```
In [181]: a, b = np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([5,6,7,8,9,10])                                           
In [182]: b[a]                                                                                         
Out[182]: array([6, 7, 8])
In [183]: def foo(arr, eva): 
     ...:     return eva[arr] 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [184]: foo(a,b)                                                                                     
Out[184]: array([6, 7, 8])
In [186]: timeit foo(a,b)                                                                              
350 ns ± 9.98 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Trying to replicate it (and may be speed it up) with `numba`:

```
In [185]: import numba                                                                                 

In [187]: @numba.njit 
     ...: def foo1(arr,eva): 
     ...:     return eva[arr] 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [188]: foo1(a,b)                                                                                    
Out[188]: array([6, 7, 8])
In [189]: timeit foo1(a,b)                                                                             
968 ns ± 19.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [190]: @numba.njit 
     ...: def foo2(arr,eva): 
     ...:     res = np.empty(len(arr), eva.dtype) 
     ...:     for i in range(len(arr)): 
     ...:         res[i] = b[a[i]] 
     ...:     return res 

In [191]: foo2(a,b)                                                                                    
Out[191]: array([6, 7, 8])
In [192]: timeit foo2(a,b)                                                                             
941 ns ± 7.91 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [193]: @numba.njit 
     ...: def foo2(arr,eva): 
     ...:     res = np.empty(len(arr), eva.dtype) 
     ...:     for i,v in enumerate(a): 
     ...:         res[i] = b[v] 
     ...:     return res 

In [194]: foo2(a,b)                                                                                    
Out[194]: array([6, 7, 8])
In [195]: timeit foo2(a,b)                                                                             
941 ns ± 17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Not much point in trying to replace a basic `numpy` functionality with `numba`.

Someone with more `numba` experience might improve on this.

### edit

As I initially observed, `numba` does not like to index with a list.  Converting the list to array works:

```
In [196]: @numba.njit 
     ...: def prueba(arr, eva): 
     ...:     mask = [] 
     ...:     for i in range(len(arr)): 
     ...:         mask.append(arr[i]) 
     ...:     mask = np.array(mask) 
     ...:     return eva[mask] 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [197]: prueba(a,b)                                                                                  
Out[197]: array([6, 7, 8])
In [198]: timeit prueba(a,b)                                                                           
1.5 µs ± 4.79 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: But you have assumed that the length of the array "res" is known, and so you have omitted the append method, however, in my full code I need to use append, as there are conditionals along the way

Comment: I added your append code with correction.  In your initial question it seemed to be an unnecessary step.